# How to split using delimiter saved in a variable

Tags: python

I have a script where I want the user to input the delimiter on which every line in the file should be split. However, once I save this delimiter in a variable, I can no longer use it as a delimiter in the split() function. Any workarounds?

Example which does not work:

```
a='"\t"'
my_line.split(a)
```

Comment: Share how `my_line` is looks like. And what *"does not work"* means? Share current and desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have extra quotes in your delimeter. `split` takes those additional `'` also as a part of your delimiter causing issues. `split` ends up searching for `'\t'` instead of `\t` as expected by you.

```
a="'\t'"
```

should be

```
a="\t"
```

Answer (score 3):

That because you are making a delimiter that's 3 chars long `'` + `\t` + `'` instead of one `\t`.

Try with:

```
a="\t"
my_line.split(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

@DoubleDecker Hi, in your line of code, you have `a='"\t"'`. If you make `a` either `a="\t"` or `a='\t'` then your code will work fine. Writing `a='"\t"'` is not the same as the two above.

```
>>> a = '"\t"'
>>> a
'"\t"'
>>> b = "\t"
>>> b
"\t"
>>> c = '\t'
>>> c
'\t'
>>> a == b
False
>>> a == c
False
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In python a string object is anything that comes within a `single-quote` or `single-quote`, or something inside two of this `"""` or this `'''`. The method `split` expected a string object to be its parameter

```
string.split(s[, sep[, maxsplit]])
```

[Link to doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)

What you've passed in is a `'"\t"'`So it's a `"\t"` string.

You might have been confused when it came to quotes, but understanding what a method expects as an argument (reading the docs help) and understanding the the python docs will help you. Basically, read the docs.

**TL;DR**
Use

```
a = '\t' #if you wanted to use TAB as the delimiter
#Remember it's expecting a string obj
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    my_line='No suggested  \tjump to results Extension \tfor detecting mobile devices, managing   mobile view'
    a='\t'
    print(my_line.split(a))

**RESULT:**  ['No suggested  ', 'jump to results Extension ', 'for detecting mobile devices, managing   mobile view']
```

you can also use **a="\t" or a='\t'** instead of combination